# Image denoising using Unet architecture

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I'm new to computer vision and deep learning. I'm trying to train this Unet model https://github.com/kevinlu1211/pytorch-unet-resnet-50-encoder with Resnet50 as encoder. I want to implement it in a way that I pass two rgb images which are first processed by resnet50 and then the layers are concated before being passed to the decoder. I tried doing it and changed n_classes in the code to 3 to output a 3 channel rgb image just like the inputs but it gives me a distorted image [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQDjQ.jpg) which I don't understand why. Please help me with this.

The part in the code that I modified to process two rgb inputs by resnet50 is here -

```
    for i, block in enumerate(self.down_blocks, 2):  # for all the down blocks 
        x = block(x)
        if i == (UNetWithResnet50Encoder.DEPTH - 1):
            continue
        pre_pools[f"layer_{i}"] = x  ## creating all the down sampling layers

    pre_pools_inp2 = dict()
    pre_pools_inp2[f"layer_0"] = y
    y = self.input_block(y)  #
    pre_pools_inp2[f"layer_1"] = y 
    y = self.input_pool(y)   

    for i, block in enumerate(self.down_blocks, 2):  # for all the down blocks 
        y = block(y)
        if i == (UNetWithResnet50Encoder.DEPTH - 1):
            continue
        pre_pools_inp2[f"layer_{i}"] = y  ## creating all the down sampling layers
    x = torch.cat([x,y],1)
    x = self.bridge(x)  # this is now the bridge between down sampling and up sampling 

    for i, block in enumerate(self.up_blocks, 1):
        key = f"layer_{UNetWithResnet50Encoder.DEPTH - 1 - i}"  # now using that bridge for upsampling f
        x = block(x, pre_pools[key])
    output_feature_map = x
    x = self.out(x)
    del pre_pools
    if with_output_feature_map:
        return x, output_feature_map
    else:
        return x
```

Comment: Please share your code, to be able to help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @4.Pi.n I'm using the code from the link that I posted in the question. I have added the code which I modified and changed n_classes to 3 to output RGB image in the last conv layer.

Comment: Have you retrain the model ?, you can't not use pre-trained model, on a custom dataset or some changes in the architecture, without retrain it.

Comment: I'm just training the decoder part by freezing the encoder layers. What I don't understand is why the output image is like that?

Comment: Number of classes have been changed, so you need to retrain both.

Comment: Can I keep the number of classes same and get 3 channels in the output somehow? I read that changing the last layer in unet does that for you but I don't know what to do as its using n_classes in the last year

Comment: Encoder and decoder usually share some weights (features), you are using Unet with Resnet it's' a quit deep network so these changes might affect the performance, it's better to try fine tuning instead (just freeze some early encoder layers for example).

Comment: Thanks a million for your help but like I said I'm a newbie, trying to learn. Would you be able to provide any references for tuning the pretrained encoder?

Comment: Tuning is not an architecture specific, but you might try to get, what fine-tuning is, if you are not familiar with, 

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html

https://www.allerin.com/blog/how-to-fine-tune-your-artificial-intelligence-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your achitecture as you didn't post it. However, here's the architecture of a UNet that I use for Diffusion Model and it works for any image size (rectangular/square).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import math
import warnings
import os
import sys
import getpass
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import List, Union, Callable

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
os.environ['MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY'] = '1'
os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '1'
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
os.system('clear')
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

class ConvBlock(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, filters = [64, 64], padding = 'valid', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filters = filters
        self.padding = padding
        self.build()

    def build(self, input_dim = None):
        self.convs = [
                        layers.Conv2D(filters = f, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, 
                                      padding = self.padding, activation = tf.keras.activations.swish,
                                      kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(), 
                                      name = f"{self.name}_conv_{i+1}")
                        for i, f in enumerate(self.filters)
                     ]
        self.batch_norms = [
                                layers.BatchNormalization(name = f"{self.name}_batch_norm_{i+1}") 
                                for i, _ in enumerate(self.filters)
                           ]

    def call(self, inp, training = None):
        y = tf.identity(inp)
        for conv, bn in zip(self.convs, self.batch_norms):
            y = conv(y)
            y = bn(y)

        return y

class SinusoidalEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embedding_min_frequency = 1.0, 
                       embedding_max_frequency = 1000.0, 
                       embedding_dims = 32, 
                       **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        assert embedding_dims % 2 == 0, f"[SinusoidalEmbedding] `embedding_dims` must be even. Found {embedding_dims}"
        self.embedding_min_frequency = embedding_min_frequency
        self.embedding_max_frequency = embedding_max_frequency
        self.embedding_dims = embedding_dims

    def call(self, x, training = None):
        embedding_min_frequency = 1.0
        frequencies = tf.math.exp(
                                    tf.linspace(tf.math.log(self.embedding_min_frequency), 
                                                tf.math.log(self.embedding_max_frequency), self.embedding_dims // 2)
                                )
        angular_speeds = tf.cast(2.0 * math.pi * frequencies, tf.float32)
        embeddings = tf.concat([tf.math.sin(angular_speeds * x), tf.math.cos(angular_speeds * x)], axis = -1)
        return embeddings


class DenoisingUNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_dim: Iterable = (28, 28),
                       num_channels: int = 1, 
                       depth: int = 5, 
                       filters: List[int] = [64, 128, 256, 512, 1024],
                       last_layer_activation: Callable = tf.identity,
                       add_sinusoidal_embedding = True,
                       embedding_min_frequency = None,
                       embedding_max_frequency = None,
                       embedding_dims = None,
                       **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        assert len(input_dim) == 2, f"input_dim must be of the form (img_height, img_width). Found input_dim = {input_dim}"
        assert len(filters) == depth, f"Number of filters must be same as depth. Found filters = {filters}, depth = {depth}"
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.num_channels = num_channels
        self.depth = depth
        self.filters = filters
        self.add_sinusoidal_embedding = add_sinusoidal_embedding
        if add_sinusoidal_embedding:
            assert embedding_min_frequency is not None, "please provide embedding_min_frequency"
            assert embedding_max_frequency is not None, "please provide embedding_max_frequency"
            assert embedding_dims is not None, "please provide embedding_dims"
            self.embedding_min_frequency = embedding_min_frequency
            self.embedding_max_frequency = embedding_max_frequency
            self.embedding_dims = embedding_dims
        
        self.kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
        self.built = False

    def build(self, input_dim = None):

        up_path_paddings = ['valid' for _ in range(self.depth - 2)]
        up_path_paddings.append('same')

        if self.add_sinusoidal_embedding:
            self.sin_embed = SinusoidalEmbedding(embedding_min_frequency = self.embedding_min_frequency,
                                                 embedding_max_frequency = self.embedding_max_frequency,
                                                 embedding_dims = self.embedding_dims)

        self.context_reshaper = tf.keras.Sequential([
                                                    layers.Dense(self.input_dim[0], activation = tf.nn.tanh),
                                                    layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1)),
                                                    layers.Dense(self.input_dim[1], activation = tf.nn.tanh),
                                                    layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1))
                                                ], name = 'context_reshaper')

        self.context_reshaper.trainable = False

        self.down_path_convs = [
                                ConvBlock(filters = [f, f], name = f'conv_block_{i+1}') 
                                for i, f in enumerate(self.filters)
                               ]
        
        self.poolers = [
                        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2, name = f"max_pool_{i+1}")
                        for i in range(self.depth - 1)
                       ]
        
        self.upsamplers = [
                            layers.UpSampling2D(size = 2, name = f"upsampling_{i+1}")
                            for i in range(self.depth - 1)
                          ]
        
        rev_filters = list(reversed(self.filters))
        self.up_path_convs = [
                                ConvBlock(filters = [rev_filters[i], rev_filters[i+1]],
                                          padding = padding,
                                          name = f"up_path_conv_block_{i+1}")
                                for i, padding in enumerate(up_path_paddings)
                             ]

        self.concats = [
                        layers.Concatenate(name = f"concat_{i+1}")
                        for i in range(self.depth - 1)
                        ]

        self.de_conv = tf.keras.Sequential(
                                        [
                                            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters = self.filters[0],
                                                                   kernel_size = 3,
                                                                   strides = 1,
                                                                   padding = 'valid',
                                                                   activation = tf.keras.activations.swish,
                                                                   kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer),
                                            layers.BatchNormalization(),
                                            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters = self.filters[0],
                                                                   kernel_size = 3,
                                                                   strides = 1,
                                                                   padding = 'valid',
                                                                   activation = tf.keras.activations.swish,
                                                                   kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer),
                                            layers.BatchNormalization(),
                                            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters = self.num_channels,
                                                                   kernel_size = 1,
                                                                   strides = 1,
                                                                   padding = 'valid',
                                                                   activation = tf.identity,
                                                                   kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer),
                                        ], name = 'DeConvBlock'
                                        )

        self.built = True

    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, inp, embed_inp = None, context = None, training = None):     
        if not self.built:
            self.build()

        inp = tf.cast(inp, tf.float32)
        embed_inp = tf.cast(embed_inp, tf.float32)
        if context is not None:
            context = tf.cast(context, tf.float32)

        if self.add_sinusoidal_embedding:
            assert embed_inp is not None, "Provide an `embed_inp` to be embedded sinusoidally"
            embed_inp = self.sin_embed(embed_inp, training = training)
            embed_inp = layers.UpSampling2D(size = self.input_dim)(embed_inp)

        if False:
            # assert context.shape[1:] == (), f"context should be a scalar of shape (batch_size, ). Found context.shape = {context.shape}"
            # context = context[..., tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]
            context = self.context_reshaper(context)
            x = tf.concat([inp, embed_inp, context], axis = -1)
        else:
            self.context_reshaper = None
            x = tf.concat([inp, embed_inp], axis = -1)
        
        skips = []
        for pool, conv in zip(self.poolers, self.down_path_convs):
            x = conv(x)
            skips.append(x)
            x = pool(x)

        x = self.down_path_convs[-1](x)

        for upsample, concat, conv in zip(self.upsamplers, self.concats, self.up_path_convs):
            x = upsample(x)
            y = skips.pop()
            x =  tf.image.resize(images = x, size = y.shape[1:3])
            x = concat([x, y])
            x = conv(x)

        op = self.de_conv(x)

        return op

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inp, embed_inp = None, context = None, training = None):
        return self.__call__(inp = inp, embed_inp = embed_inp, context = context, training = training)

    
    @tf.function
    def create_weights(self, add_context = True):
        inp = tf.random.normal((1, *self.input_dim, self.num_channels))
        if self.add_sinusoidal_embedding:
            embed_inp = tf.random.normal((1, 1, 1, 1))
        else:
            embed_inp = None

        if add_context:
            context = tf.random.normal((1, 10))
        else:
            context = None
        op = self(inp = inp, embed_inp = embed_inp, context = context)
        return True


    def summary(self, inp_shape: List[Iterable]):
        assert len(inp_shape) <= 3, f"At most 3 inputs are taken into DenoisingUNet"
        if len(inp_shape) == 1:
            inp_layer = layers.Input((*inp_shape[0], self.num_channels))
            inputs = [inp_layer]
        elif len(inp_shape) == 2:
            inp_layer = layers.Input((*inp_shape[0], self.num_channels))
            embed_inp_layer = layers.Input(inp_shape[1])
            inputs = [inp_layer, embed_inp_layer]
        else:
            inp_layer = layers.Input((*inp_shape[0], self.num_channels))
            embed_inp_layer = layers.Input(inp_shape[1])
            context_inp_layer = layers.Input(inp_shape[2])
            inputs = [inp_layer, embed_inp_layer, context_inp_layer]

        op = self.call(*inputs)
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = op, name = '2D-DenoisingUNet')
        model.summary()

    def plot(self, inp_shape):
        assert len(inp_shape) <= 3, f"At most 3 inputs are taken into DenoisingUNet"
        if len(inp_shape) == 1:
            inp_layer = layers.Input((*inp_shape[0], self.num_channels))
            inputs = [inp_layer]
        elif len(inp_shape) == 2:
            inp_layer = layers.Input((*inp_shape[0], self.num_channels))
            embed_inp_layer = layers.Input(inp_shape[1])
            inputs = [inp_layer, embed_inp_layer]
        else:
            inp_layer = layers.Input((*inp_shape[0], self.num_channels))
            embed_inp_layer = layers.Input(inp_shape[1])
            context_inp_layer = layers.Input(inp_shape[2])
            inputs = [inp_layer, embed_inp_layer, context_inp_layer]

        op = self.call(*inputs)
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = op, name = '2D-DenoisingUNet')
        tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes = True, to_file = '2DDenoisingUNet.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unet = DenoisingUNet(input_dim = (64, 64),
                         num_channels = 3,
                         depth = 3,
                         filters = [64, 128, 256],
                         add_sinusoidal_embedding = True,
                         embedding_min_frequency = 1.0,
                         embedding_max_frequency = 1000.0,
                         embedding_dims = 32)
    unet.plot(inp_shape = [(64, 64), (1, 1, 1), (64, )])
    unet.summary(inp_shape = [(64, 64), (1, 1, 1), (64, )])
```

The above code is an example for image size of (64, 64, 3). I tried it for image size of (224, 224, 3) (ImageNet) and (178, 218, 3) (CelebA) and it works fine.